# Polytope: from $\mathcal H$-representation to $\mathcal V$-representation

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, computational-geometry, polytopes

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299959/characterize-polytopes-resulting-from-cutting-a-convex-polytope-by-a-hyperplane) nicely explains how to go from a vertex representation ($\mathcal{V}$) to a half-space representation ($\mathcal{H}$) of a polytope. But I don't fully understand how to go from a half-space representation to a vertex representation.

I am using the QuickHull algorithm to go from a vertex representation to a half-space representation ($\mathcal{V}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$). But I should be able to use the same algorithm to go from $\mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{V}$, given that these problems are equivalent?

Comment: Only bounded H-polytopes have a V-representation, right?